# Testing Custom Payment Gateway

Tags: ee2, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate PayU as payment gateway into my ExpressionEngine2 website, but battling to make the code fit and understand where I need to put what code (I wrote an extension for the gateway using the sample code I downloaded from PayU's website using sendData() and getData() functions in the gateway). How could I actually test that the payment gateway code is actually being read?

My page flow is as follows:

Credit Card Page -> PayU Gateway -> Success Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayU should be able to provide you with dummy credit card test details so you can test the whole process start to finish.